# add LinearLayout via addContentView(). Sliding drawer now beneath the last added Content

Tags: android, android-layout

Friends,

i have a xml file including a Sliding drawer. 
I setContentView in the start of the application.

I create dynamically a LinearLayout in Java with a few TextViews and Edittext and add it to the application via addContentView(). 
The SlidingDrawer still works but LinearLayout i added via addContentView() is displayed above the SlidingDrawer.
Is there a way to make the SlidingDrawer work correct?

Heres part of my code

```
            setContentView(R.layout.real_time_report_layout);
            LinearLayout linearLayoutRealTimeReportActivity = new LinearLayout(ctx);


            TextView tv_questionType1 = new TextView(ctx);

    linearLayoutRealTimeReportActivity.addView(tv_questionType1);

             addContentView(linearLayoutRealTimeReportActivity, layoutParamsRealTimeReportActivity);
```

I m glad for any support also work around!!!

heres my xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_real_time_report_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_real_time_report_send"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="@string/b_real_time_report_send" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_real_time_report_cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="@string/b_real_time_report_cancel" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/sd_real_time_report_layout_SlidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/sd_real_time_report_layout_handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sd_real_time_report_layout_handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" >
    </Button>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mv_real_time_report"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:apiKey="0IfKjDM6XzpM6rGFR0H6X03Y1aWVBOnJ1C8b6wQ"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_real_time_report_userLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:textSize="20dp" >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_real_time_report_deleteUserLocationPin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/b_real_time_report_deleteUserLocationPin" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tb_real_time_report_chooseLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textOff="@string/tb_real_time_report_ChooseLocationOFF"
            android:textOn="@string/tb_real_time_report_ChooseLocationON" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need slight changes.

- Give an id to your parent `LinearLayout` in layout xml (let's say, `android:id="@+id/parent_container"`).
- You will get your `LinearLayout` in java file.

something like this:

```
LinearLayout container=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.parent_container);
```

- Now when adding new `View` to `container` we will use index to put view at specific index.

something like this:

```
container.addView(linearLayoutRealTimeReportActivity, container.getChildCount()-2);
```

We substracted -2 because we want to put View at second last index.
So `SlidingDrawer` is still at the last index.

Comment: Thanks Adil!!! I did not even need the index. Just give the LinearLayout an id and addView to the LinearLayout.

Comment: Cool, I was considering that you have `SlidingDrawer` in your `LinearLayout`. Happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

Android draws Views in order of adding them to the container, so your view will be drawn under Drawer.

The easiest soluition would probably be to add your cusom view to FrameLayout (or any other layout) defined in xml.